# Why does Krishna say that "I am the light of the sun and the moon..." when the moon has no light of its own?

Tags: scripture, krishna, bhagavad-gita, gita

Chapter 7 Shloka 8: O son of Kunti, I am the taste of water, the light of the sun and the moon, the syllable om in the Vedic mantras; I am the sound in ether and ability in man.

Why did Krishna not clarify that he's talking about the reflected light of the sun coming from the moon?

Comment: If your question is based on science, science is yet to prove that Krishna is light of sun, and yet to prove that there is Krishna. Irrelevant question. Think from a spiritual level and then you'll see the light coming from moon and you'll also see Krishna in that.

Comment: He is making reference that He is the source of the light. That He is the source of everything.

Comment: You are reading poetry, okay. Do not forget that. It is not an essay. Moon light is a very common poetic expression.

Comment: @r-kaushik may be you need to post a question and answer why vishanava ithihasa is not for reading! bold claim; need to be substantiated.

Comment: I have answered up to the level Krishna has illuminated my intellect. Maybe it will be of help to you guys.

Comment: MY ANSWER & COMMENTS ARE ALL DELETED !!! Vishnu's tamasic nature is given in our Shaiva scriptures and you are suppressing Shiv-Shakti followers.... giving preference to Vaishnavas & Smartas.

Comment: @R.Kaushik That's very unfair. Did they give a reason as to why your answer was deleted?

Comment: @R Kaushik Just so you know,you believe that Shaiva scriptures are supremely true(without explaining on the basis of **facts**,in our old conversation).And you take this as a licence to debase Vaishnav scripture.Your language is very strong,yet you base it on opinions,this may be a reason why it got deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Lokesh ! I was told that it is offensive to Vaishnavas :( Then I was told that I could edit and undelete it.... but I get the message "you cannot undelete" it... Anyways 5-10 Vaishnavas & Smartas moderators will not listen to 1 Shaiva or Shakta

Comment: @R.Kaushik I feel the same, mods here misuse their power. They are afraid of truth. In other sites, no one deletes an answer unless it has abuse language in it. But here they have too much censorship. They don't understand that if the answer is too bad, then other people can simply downvote it. There's no need to delete it.

Comment: @Lokesh so sad... this website has become a tool for sectarian propaganda

Comment: @R.Kaushik Vishnu's tamasic nature? What are you even talking about? Krishna himself says in the Bhagavad Gita that he is above the three material modes of Sattva, Rajas, and Tamas. What scripture do you speak of that says Vishnu is tamasic? I believe that text to be false and it definitely cannot be above the Bhagavad Gita. Also, Shiva himself was born from Brahma and Brahma himself was born from Vishnu's naval. Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 10, Verse 2 - Neither celestial gods nor the great sages know my origin. I am the source from which the gods and great seers come.

Comment: @R.Kaushik Every avatar of Krishna has impacted the earth and human beings in a major way. Shivji has always assisted Krishna by taking the form of Hanuman ji or by giving Pashupatastra to Arjuna. Shivji even asked for Krishna's help in defeating Bhasmasur. Shivji even had difficulty defeating his own son Ganesha. And no scripture you cite or quote will be greater than the Bhagavad Gita. No matter how deluded of a bhakt of Shivji you are.

Comment: **100% LIES!!** 1) avatars of Krishna? lol. Krishna was just an avatar as per Mahabharat itself. 2) Bhasmasura story in Tamasic Vaishnava scriptures is bogus... according to Shaiva Puranas it is only Lord Shiva who protected the Devas from Bhasmasura !!! Example - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc365968.html in the same section Vishnu says he will pray to the Supreme Lord Mahadeva along with the other devas for help !!! 3) Ganesha badly beat Vishnu who is only Shiva's SERVANT !!! https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226136.html

Comment: EVERY SINGLE Shaiva & Shakta scripture is above Bhagavad Gita which has many errors. For example - it also says that Vishwaroop is being shown for the first time but MBH already mentioned that Rama had shown his Vishwaroop before !! You are the only one who is highly deluded !! **Even junior most Tantrik has many more suprenatural powers than most advanced Vaishnav guru ... there is no concept of third eye awakening or kundalini in Vaishnav scriptures. You people have ZERO POWERS !!** BG cannot help you. Better to read Avadhoot Gita. One of Shiva's names is "the one who slashes Vishnu's head."

Comment: @R.Kaushik I read your link. Nowhere it says Ganesha badly beat Vishnu. Whenever Vishnu pretends to fall, it's leela, to please his devotees (Shiv & Parvati) of the strength of the powers Krishna has granted them. Bramhaji says in Bramha Samhita 5.1 - "Krsna who is known as Govinda is the Supreme Godhead. He has an eternal blissful spiritual body. He is the origin of all. He has no other origin and He is the prime cause of all causes. "

Comment: @R.Kaushik And in Srimad Bhagavatam 11.34 Shivji says - "My dear Devī, although the Vedas recommend worship of demigods, the worship of Lord Viṣṇu is topmost. However, above the worship of Lord Viṣṇu is the rendering of service to Vaiṣṇavas, who are related to Lord Viṣṇu."

Comment: @R.Kaushik Shivji's avatar Hanuman chants Lord Ram's (Krishna's) name incessantly. Why do you think that it? Shivji is a bhakt of Krishna. Shivji performs austerities but Krishna never does. Krishna simply plays his flute, takes care of cows, plays with his friends, etc. That's because Krishna has no need of anything. He is the supreme.

Comment: PRETENDS? haha... you're just making stuff up to make **SERVANT vishnu** look stronger than he is!! He is not capable of doing leela. And **Brahma samhita is NOT an authentic scripture** it was FABRICATED by Chaitanya and even so Samhitas are not sacred like Agamas, Puranas, Itihasas, secret scriptures etc. Ramayana is a Tamasic Vaishnava Itihasa which is not to be read by Brahmins... the Shaiva Itihasa is the only true Itihasa... *Hanuman was ONLY a part of Rudra** and still had more power than Rama. **Rama WORSHIPPED Shiva before going to Lanka!!!** It again shows Vishnu is a SERVANT of Shiv

Comment: **Srimad Bhagvat is a 100% TAMASIC SCRIPTURE** not meant for Brahmins. Meaning it is harmful to read.... 1) Ganesha beat up Vishnu. 2) Asura Tara beat up Vishnu by throwing him 100 YOJANAS away and Vishnu ran away 3) Dadhicha beat up Vishnu 4) Rudra killed Vishnu..... so many more examples.... **Vishnu was TOO WEAK to win!!** Vaishnava scriptures don't even know what kundalini means hahahaha NOT A SINGLE VAISHNAV has supernatural power like third eye !!! And Brahma is not worshipped because Shaiva scriptures are right and true. **Krishna is dead** . was just an avatar stop acting like he lives

Answer (score 4):

Well, I asked only because if someone else asks me this, I should have an answer. Here is how I justify it -

1. Krishna did not use plural or separate the two lights as different from each other. He did not say "I am the light of the Sun and the light of the moon" OR "I am the lights of the sun and the moon". Singular use of the word light signifies that he knows that it's the same light.
2. Once you borrow something or once someone donates you something, it is yours. Moon takes/borrows light from the Sun and whenever we refer to light coming from the moon, we always say moonlight and don't say that it is sunlight or reflected sunlight. We use the term moonlight. So even if Krishna meant it as separate, it is separate since it now belongs to the moon.

Will add more thoughts as and when Krishna blesses my intellect. Hare Krishna fellow jivas!

Source: My brain

Comment: Wow... mind blowing.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Source of what? The shloka itself is from Chapter 7, shloka 8 as written in the question itself. And as for the answer, it is from me with Krishna's help.

Comment: Namaste and Welcome to the site! Please refer: [Guidelines for new users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Answers must be backed by scriptural references and hence as per site rules your brain is not a valid source.

Comment: @Archit I've used simple step by step logic. As per you, I would have to publish my thoughts in a book and then mention it as a source? How's that reasonable? Do you even believe in God? Krishna himself says in the Gita and here's the source, BG 7.10 - "I am the intelligence of the intelligent." So the ultimate source for my answer is Krishna as I have mentioned in the 2nd last line. Have some confidence in yourself. Be a man. Why do you consider yourself lesser than another human who has written something in a book that you need to quote from? Some questions need logic to derive answers from.

Comment: @DragonDroid please don’t misunderstand. The site rules aren’t telling you to quote from another book. They’re advising to quote from religious texts like Puranas, Vedas, Gita (directly) etc. It’s very good if Bhagwan helps you and you are very lucky indeed but the sages’ intellect was closer to god than either of us. You are trusting the sages who wrote these books not mere humans. Maximum any commentaries on these, again helped by God more than he helps either of us. So, yes I do believe in God, but we aren’t above site rules, until people have faith in your enlightenment like Vyasa etc.

Comment: @dragon droid I appreciate the devotion , but our Sanatan scriptures are not meant to read in Islamic ways.

Answer (score 4):

This is unnecessary complicating of a poetic language used in the gita. If someone says your face is like moon, it doesn't mean you have 16 scars on your face. Most probably IMHO, Krishna was speaking poetically saying I'm all the light that there is. In the light of Sun and in the light of Moon

If at all you want to philosophise this, then it can mean that Krishna is saying that, He's the original light and the reflected light. As both a the property of producing light and reflecting light is possible only if God allows so.