# Lord krishna said "Tejah of the moon is from me"? What is mean by that?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I've read this answer in which [lord krishna say "I
m the light of sun and moon"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48236/why-does-krishna-say-that-i-am-the-light-of-the-sun-and-the-moon-when-the-m) which is justify in grammatical way.

But I've read another verse , in which lord krishna said *Tejah* from the sun is from me, and *tejah* from the moon is also from me.

> यदादित्यगतं तेजो जगद्भासयतेऽखिलम्‌ । यच्चन्द्रमसि यच्चाग्नौ तत्तेजो
> विद्धि मामकम्‌
>
> The splendor of the sun, which dissipates the darkness of this whole
> world, comes from Me. And the splendor of the moon and the splendor of
> fire are also from Me.
>
> Chapter 15 : Verse 12

Here *tejah* means splender according to bhagwad gita as it is. But in sanskrit *tejah* means *light*. *(Particulary light from the sun)*.

So can someone please help me to understand this verse? Since moon doesn't light itself.

Comment: I visit your house and leave a gift with you.  A few days later another gift arrives in the mail.  One gift was given directly and one indirectly, but both gifts were "from me".  If one of those gifts was a candle, then even though *you* light it, that light is a also gift "from me".

Comment: The whole prakriti belongs to him. May be shree krishna just want to say that all the tejah which you see from the sun, moon and fire all belongs to him. Since he is medium also. But still I want more clarification from others if they have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tejah generally does not mean light, it sort of means bright. The Supreme Personality of Godhead, Krishna says that the moons brightness is because of him. And even though moon takes light from the sun and Krishna also gives light to the sun hence Moon directly and indirectly takes light from Krishna.

I hope this answers your doubt.

Hare Krishna!